# `:bro w` initially opens wrong directory in 8.1.1

Tags: working-directory

I just upgraded Vim to 8.1.1, and the behavior of `:bro w` seems changed: it occasionally (!?) does not open the pwd for browsing.  (I checked `:pwd`.)  This in on Win 10.  Does something other than the pwd determine which directory should be browsed?  I still get the expected behavior if I specify a directory, and if I do that once, the old behavior (i.e., following the pwd) is restored.

As possible context, I `set autochdir` in my _vimrc, so my current buffer sets my pwd.  I checked `browsedir` and it says `buffer`.

**Edit:**

After closing and relaunching GVim, I can no longer produce this behavior.  So my question changes to: has anyone else experienced this behavior?

Comment: According to docs, `:browse w` should use directory of current buffer. When it doesnt use pwd, what does it use? Does removing autochdir solve the problem?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Yes, that is how I understand the docs too.  Instead, it remained stuck in the first directory I used.  However, now I cannot reproduce this behavior. I am going to have to gather more info.